# Does WebSphere 7 support Integrated Windows Authentication?

Tags: websphere, windows-authentication

Is [Integrated Windows Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication) available in WebSphere (7)?

Specifically, how is it possible to obtain the username and group memberships of the user accessing a web application via a IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPNEGO is supported on was7 see [Creating a single sign-on for HTTP requests using SPNEGO Web authentication](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/csec_SPNEGO_explain.html)

As specified in the doc:

> The requester's identity in the WebSphere Application Server security registry must be identical to the identity that the SPNEGO web authentication retrieves. An identical match does occur when Microsoft Windows Active Directory server is the Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) server that is used in WebSphere Application Server.

Which means that `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()` will return you the actual username.

You can perform ldap operations through jndi see [JNDI as an LDAP API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/jndi.html) However I would prefer mapping groups to roles to determine group membership.